# NDP (icmpV6) Implementation: Duplicate packets send by Kernel

Tags: ipv6, icmp

I have tried to develop and implement NDP(Neighbor Discovery Protocol) in Linux based PC's referring RFC 4861.

I have created a socket `socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IPV6)`. NS/NA packet (ipv6 header + icmpv6 header+options) are filled and send by developer itself.

In Wireshark, I have monitored that NS packet which I have filled is being send + Kernel sends NS packets of its own and receives NA packets.

So I am confused and stuck in my work. Can anyone please help and explain

1. Why this duplicate packets generated by kernel of its own?
2. If kernel handles ICMPv6 packets, which is the scenario where NDP should be developed and implemented?

Answer (score 3):

The kernel already implements NDP so a developer doesn't have to, just like you don't implement ARP for IPv4.

If you still want to implement ND (for instance because it is an assigned school project), you will have to find a way to disable it in the kernel (may be removing the code and recompiling).